# react native: appregistry error on launching app for first time

Tags: react-native

Invariant Violation: "reactNative" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

changes i did:
moved app.tsx to src folder.

index.js:

```js
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Comment: Before you do your change "moved app.tsx to src folder", did your app run without problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that both app.json and package.json have the same name, and ensure that the main activity also has the same name.